# I am using flask_uploads and am getting this error ImportError: cannot import name 'patch_request_class' from 'flask_uploads'

Tags: flask, flask-uploads, flask-reuploaded

my code looks like this

```
from flask_uploads import IMAGES, UploadSet, configure_uploads, patch_request_class
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = os.path.join(basedir, 'static/images')
photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES)

configure_uploads(app, photos)
patch_request_class(app)
```

what could be the issue. Can I get any help on how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very recently, `patch_request_class` was removed from `Flask-Reuploaded`, the maintained fork of `Flask-Uploads`, which gets installed as `flask_uploads` to stay compatible (and so you did not need to change imports).

Are you sure you use `Flask-Uploads` and not `Flask-Reuploaded`? Have a look at your requirements.txt or setup.py.

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/commit/55c7721b5905ecf5ec2e6c46dcf3073ac78df632) where `patch_request_class` gets removed.

As you can read, `patch_request_class` was deprecated for a long time already, and it was only necessary to restrict uploads up to Flask version 0.6. Since then you can use the `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` environment variable of Flask itself, see  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH

**tl/dr**

- remove the `patch_request_class` import
- remove `patch_request_class(app)`
- set `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` to desired value

Comment: Hi Eric, as I wrote in my answer, `patch_request_class` is a ancient function, and it was only needed for Flask version 0.6 - Flask 2.0 will be released shortly. Also, `Flask-Uploads` has not seen a new release in many years. `Flask-Reuploaded` is the way to go, as it is actively maintained, and even a security risk in `Flask-Uploads` was fixed in `Flask-Reuploaded`. As I described above, the way forward is to remove `patch_request_class` from your code and to use `Flask-Reuploaded`.

Comment: If you use an application you don't develop, you may need this deprecated function. To use previous version, you can use
`pip install git+https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded@53234dd`
which will install the library just before it was removed.